# Why there is interval between canvas and div element below?

Tags: css, html5-canvas

I have set borders and margins to zero.

```
<div class='nobordermargin'>hello</div>

<canvas class='nobordermargin' id="myCanvas" 
width="300" height="150"></canvas>

<div class='nobordermargin'>hello</div>
```

[The jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/gawuyimaje/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set `canvas` to `{ display: block; }` as it's `inline` by default.

[JSBin Snapshot](https://jsbin.com/mebuqatitu/2/edit?html,css,output)

Also see here: [Inline Elements | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)